# Не запускается симулятор в Playground на базе Xcode

Tags: xcode, swift, playground

Вхожу в Playgroud, работаю, но ни разу не запускается симулятор на данной платформе, все время крутится спиннер загрузки, потом даже замирает в одном положении,

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но симулятор так и не запускается, причем, что характерно, вначале выдается сообщение с тем же крутящимся спиннером о том, что симулятор загружается, - "Running simulator" потом отображается, что все готово - "Ready", но необходимый функционал так и не загружается.

Пока так:

[image]

И кстати, что еще показательно, некоторые функции, как видно на изображении выше, не подгружаются, и их нельзя использовать! А должно быть примерно как-то так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно, может дело в самой операционной системе, в её мощности, пока что у меня следующие системные параметры:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Очень похоже на глюки Playground.
У меня такое поведение тоже бывают, хотя технические показатели намного выше. Возможно нужено переустановить xCode.

Я делаю `Run` вручную (ставлю галочку на ручной запуск):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть мнение, что если удалить самый верхний комментарии и убрать пробелы то проблема проподает, но мне не помогло.

Comment: Пробовал переустанавливать, проблема осталась, ручной запуск тоже не помогает

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась, банально, обновлением Xcode до новой версии. Теперь если Симулятор не запускается, достаточно нажать комбинацию клавиш Shift+Return, и все! Если выдаст ошибку, что мол не загружен модуль - модуль загружается, достаточно снова нажать соответствующую комбинацию клавиш. Также появилась функция нажатия на клавишу запуска, как на видео-плеерах, непосредственно в коде, чтобы запустить симулятор!